# Taylor expansion in derivation of Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: taylor-expansion, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

[image]

I got this from QFT Demystified in the author attempt to derive the Euler Lagrange equation. But isn't the Taylor expansion for $f(x+a)$ supposed to be:
$$f(x+a)=f(a)+x\frac{df(a)}{dx}+...(1)$$
Even if I exchange $x\rightarrow \epsilon, a \rightarrow x$, it should have been:
$$f(\epsilon+x)=f(x)+\epsilon\frac{df(x)}{d\epsilon}+...(2)$$

I understand that in (1), $a$ is the point where we start or "nail" the fitting process, and $x$ is the independent variable. But what are $\epsilon$ and $x$ in (2)? Feel free to be rigorous if there's no intuitive way to answer, cause I really don't understand Taylor expansion at all and I need any answer. :((

Thank you! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac{\mathrm d V(x)}{\mathrm d x}=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{V(x+\varepsilon)-V(x)}{\varepsilon}
$$
so for $\varepsilon\ll 1$ we can write

$$
\frac{\mathrm d V(x)}{\mathrm d x}\approx \frac{V(x+\varepsilon)-V(x)}{\varepsilon}
$$
that is
$$
V(x+\varepsilon)\approx V(x)  + \varepsilon \frac{\mathrm d V(x)}{\mathrm d x}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The confusion arises because of the notation you are using. Write (1) as
$$f(x+a)=f(a)+xf'(a).$$
Now proceed as you suggest and replace $x$ by $\epsilon$ and $a$ by $x$. This yields
$$f(\epsilon+x)=f(x)+\epsilon f'(x).$$
Is it clearer now?